# Multivariate Time Series Analysis

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis

I am a newbie in statistics, however my job requires me to do a Multivariate time series analysis.

I have 32 observations. Main independent variable, dependent variable and 4 other variable which I will control. This is basically to understand how GDP (i.v) effects the main D.V.

Now i am confused, what to do? which model to use? log? and lag values? checking data whether it is stationary, how should i do that?

Can Please someone tell me step by step direction, how should I go ahead with this?

please help.

Comment: There are too many questions here for a Q&A website. I think it would be better if you provide more information about your variables/data, and especially what you have tried so far. If you have no/very limited knowledge about time series analysis, reading some introductory texts and checking tutorials might be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have number of crimes as the D.V and GDP per capita as I.V, from a single country for last 40 years. Trying to find if increase in GDP effects the crimes. I have 5 other control variables from world bank, like education, health, social welfare, development, etc. I do not know what to do now, data is time series. What should be my first step? checking stationary or non-stationary? then which model should I use? should I take log values? and which model should I apply like vector auto regression? and how to check for robustness? please help.